# Take schema ownership as a DB owner

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to take ownership of the "public" schema in the database I'm the owner of (but not superuser). I'm running `alter schema public owner to username`, where `username` is my user name. I'm getting the following error: `ERROR: must be owner of schema public`.

Is it possible for me as a non-superuser database owner to take ownership of a schema, (or generally any object) in my database?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible. You can change the ownership of any object in PostgreSQL only if you are Superuser or if you are the owner of same object.

You should ask your DBA or owner of the schema to do change the owner.